# Program PWM on Linux Embedded system

Tags: linux, module, kernel, embedded, pwm

I'm not an expert linux user. I usually program microcontrollers without OS. 
Now I have a TS7200 board from embedded arm. The board host a Linux 2.6 kernel.

What i want to do is to generate a PWM signal. I see that I have this module:
/lib/modules/2.6.36.1/kernel/drivers/misc/ep93xx_pwm.ko.

But I have no idea how to use it. How can i call the function contained in that module for example from a C program.

Note: naively my first approach to solve my original problem was try to set bits directly in the hardware register but it seems that i can't do it... I think that memory is protected by the kernel.

Note2: i tried to i implement a software pwm using first the pthreads and then the timerfd. But the kernel time granularity is 10ms so i can't do a precise pwm at 100hz. (Furthermore 100 hz is also a very bad pwm :( ) This method is also resource consuming.

Any help is really appreciated. Sorry for my bad english but is not my native language.

kind regards

Comment: Your first approach should have been to look at [the man](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/pwm.txt)

Comment: I discover how to make it work.
The ep93xx pwm driver was working in that kernel
but it had a custom sysfs interface. The device attribute nodes are created
at /sys/devices/platform/ep93xx-pwm.N (N is 0 or 1 for PWMOUT and PWMOUT1).
In that directory you should find some attributes:
min_freq        read-only       minimum PWM frequency
max_freq        read-only       maximum PWM frequency
freq | read-write      PWM output frequency (0=disable output)
duty_precent    read-write      PWM duty cycle percent (1-99 percent)
 invert  read-write  invert PWM output (0=normal, 1=inverted)